# How to access previous value of a field in django model form before save?

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to access the previous value of the Django model instance field **before saving** the form. For example in the `form_valid` method need to access previous values of the model instance. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What your mean previous value of model instance ? You mean with previous id ?

Comment: Yes. I want the previous values of the model instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use copy your previous model instance with `copy` so that when you save your new instance it donot override your previous instance:

```
import copy

if form.is_valid():
    obj = YourModel.objects.get(pk=form.instance.pk)
    prev_obj = copy.copy(obj)
    // here you can access any field of your previous object related to that instance.
    // prev_obj.field
    new_obj = form.save()
```

Note: this is only applicable if you are going to update your model not during creation.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have `MyModel` table. Now let's create `instance` of `MyModel`, and return one instance (`row`).

```
mymodel_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=14) # This returns instance of MyModel.
# Now lets get all values, before mymode_instance.
mymodel_qs = MyModel.objects.filter(pk__lt=mymodel_instance.pk) # This returns QuerySet (All values before mymodel_instance).
# iterate over all previous values.
for mymodel_obj in mymodel_qs:
    print(mymodel_obj, mymodel_obj.pk) # This will print all previous instance and id.
```

I hope, it will help you.